# Error code for exceptions that don't provide one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

```
def main():

    try:

        exit_code = 0

        # Some code that might raise an exception

    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        exit_code = error.errno
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        sys.exit(exit_code)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`ValueError` and `TypeError` don't provide an error code, because pylint gives me the following error:

```
Instance of 'ValueError' has no 'errno' memberpylint(no-member)
Instance of 'TypeError' has no 'errno' memberpylint(no-member)
```

When I want to exit my script and provide the error code to `sys.exit()`, what value should be provided for exceptions that don't return error codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you what exit stati you provide.

It is widely accepted to return 0 (sometimes called EXIT_SUCCESS) if the program finished successfully. It is also common to return 1 upon failure (EXIT_FAILURE).